# TypeError: google.maps.places.PlaceAutocompleteElement is not a constructor

Tags: laravel, vue.js, google-maps, maps

I'm trying to display the Google Maps map in my application. I'm using Vue, but I'm getting this error in the console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sxHP.png)

Register.vue

```
<script setup>
let map;

let marker;

let infoWindow;

const initMap = async () => {
    await loader.load().then(async (google) => {
        //@ts-ignore
        const [{ Map }, { AdvancedMarkerElement }] = await Promise.all([
            google.maps.importLibrary("marker"),
            google.maps.importLibrary("places"),
        ]);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: { lat: 40.749933, lng: -73.98633 },
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeControl: false,
        });

        const input = document.createElement("input");

        input.id = "pac-input";

        //@ts-ignore
        const pac = new google.maps.places.PlaceAutocompleteElement({
            inputElement: input,
        });

        const card = document.getElementById("pac-card");

        card.appendChild(pac.element);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(card);
        // Create the marker and infowindow
        marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
            map,
        });

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
        // Add the gmp-placeselect listener, and display the results on the map.
        pac.addListener("gmp-placeselect", async ({ place }) => {
            await place.fetchFields({
                fields: ["displayName", "formattedAddress", "location"],
            });
            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.location);
                map.setZoom(17);
            }

            let content =
                '<div id="infowindow-content">' +
                '<span id="place-displayname" class="title">' +
                place.displayName +
                "</span><br />" +
                '<span id="place-address">' +
                place.formattedAddress +
                "</span>" +
                "</div>";

            updateInfoWindow(content, place.location);
            marker.position = place.location;
        });
    });
};

onMounted(() => {
    initMap();
});
</script>
```

I'm following what it says on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete-new?hl=es-419#maps_place_autocomplete_map-javascript, and only that part is giving me an error

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! I noticed that you are using Vue here contrary to the vanilla JS being used in the official documentation. As that documentation uses dynamic loading of the API script, I'd assume that the loader you use is using the old way of loading the api script. This could have caused some compatibility issues. With that said, have you tried some other Autocomplete tutorials more specific to VueJS use case?

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure to enable the following APIs (within your project in google cloud console):

- `Maps JavaScript API`
- `API Places API`
- `Places API (New)`

2. specify the alpha channel:  `(v: "alpha")`  in your bootstrap loader. ( not the `beta`)
3. Include the places library :`libraries=places`